# Connection failed to hsm luna SA 'C_Initialize' returns 0x30

Tags: hsm

I tried to connect to the luna SA, with the SDK installed and the luna and  luna API.
I have access to the moon, and I could open session in putty console.
I used the login that comes in the example, but sends me an error.

code:

```
public LunaTokenManager tokenManager = null;
tokenManager = LunaTokenManager.getInstance();
try {
    tokenManager.Login(password);
}
catch (ProviderException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

to debbug stop in 
 LunaTokenManager.getInstance();

> error:
>   Exception in thread "main" com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaCryptokiException: function 'C_Initialize' returns 0x30
>       at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaCryptokiException.ThrowNew(LunaCryptokiException.java:57)
>       at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaAPI.Initialize(Native Method)
>       at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaTokenManager.(LunaTokenManager.java:107)
>       at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaTokenManager.getInstance(LunaTokenManager.java:62)

the documentation says it is not Java error, but I failed to resolve

http://leifj.nordu.net/luna-docs/007-011136-002_lunasa_5-1_webhelp_rev-a/content/sdk/jsp_errors.htm

Comment: was this issue ever resolved? I see the same issue now

Answer (score 1):

`C_Initialize` mentioned in the exception message is a function from PKCS#11 interface - lower level ANSI C API - which is probably used internally by the Java API.

`C_Initialize` returned `0x30` which is defined as `CKR_DEVICE_ERROR` which is described as "Some problem has occurred with the token and/or slot". Maybe you did not setup the connection to Luna SA properly?

I remember some certificates needed to be deployed on the client machine but I can't recall the details.

Comment: Thanks @jariq I not find that was the mistake. I have setup the connection when I installed the luna SA in Crystoki and . Also I have client certificates and server.

Comment: @bere was this issue ever resolved? I see the same issue now